# How To Restore Default Folder Attributes in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

For some odd reason folders on my computer are showing up as **unhidden** when they are supposed to be hidden, for example the *AppData* folder and some others.

When I try to check via the command line I get an error, ***file not found***.

Does anyone know of a way to restore the **default attributes** to all folders?

> NOTE: Please do not ask about hiding and showing hidden files, I know
>   all about that, this issue is **only** about restoring the *default folder attributes*.

Thank you

Comment: The exact same way you do it in Windows 7.  `Folder Options -> Restore Defaults` and `View -> Restore Defaults`

Comment: Did I say anything about the **view**? I'm talking about the attributes, which in this case have been deleted or lost somehow. [Please reread the question]

Comment: **"For some odd reason folders on my computer are showing up as unhidden"** - This behavior is handled by the folder view options.  Are the icons a `solid folder icon` or a `transparent folder icon`?

Comment: Do the files show up if you us the command-line's `DIR`?  What does `attrib` and/or Explorer report the attributes on the files/folders are set to?

Comment: ATTRIB via the command line results in `error file not found`. Dear Ramhound, the view is working fine it is the attributes which need restoring. Thank You